# MVC 5 Checkbox returns “False,false” or “false”

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

At first glance this post may look like a duplicate, but it's not. Believe me, I've looked all over Stack Overflow to no avail.

Anyway, I'm getting some weird behaviour from Html.CheckBoxFor.

I have a view model with this following defined property

```
[Display(Name = "User is active")]
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

It's initialized before the view

```
if (userInfo.isActive != null)
{
    //Cast to bool because userInfo.isActive is Nullable<bool>
    model.IsActive = (bool)userInfo.isActive;
}

ModelState.Clear();

return View(model);
```

Then rendered in an Html.BeginForm as

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive, htmlAttributes: new { @value = Model.IsActive /*Also tried @checked = Model.IsActive*/ })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive)
    </div>
</div>
```

And returned to the controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditProfile(EditProfileViewModel model, string Roles, HttpPostedFileBase ProfileImage)
{
    //There's a lot more up here, but it's not relevant to the problem
    userInfo.isActive = model.IsActive;
    var tmp = Request.Form["IsActive"]; //Added just to check the form value

    try
    {
        db.Entry(userInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;
        //Assign changed data to userInfo
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When model.IsActive is initialized as true and I don't uncheck the checkbox the value of model.IsActive in the controller post is true, or if I do uncheck the checkbox then the value of model.IsActive comes back as false and everything is hunky-dory.

The problem occurs when model.IsActive is initialized as false. I read a lot of Stack Overflow posts explaining that if the checkbox is unchecked then "false" is returned and if it is checked "true,false" is returned, but that's not the behaviour I'm getting. When the checkbox is initialized as false and I check it in the view the value of model.IsActive still comes back false and when I check the value of the form element (see "var tmp" in controller post) it's "false, false". "True,false" is the expected value, is it not? This only happens when trying to change the model value from false to true, no issues going from true to false.

So Stack Overflow, what the heck is happening?!

Comment: Just remove the `@value = Model.IsActive` from  @Html.CheckBoxFor helper and it will work fine

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, I also tried without passing in @value,doesn't make a difference. I'm considering just creating a standard HTML checkbox and just passing the value through as a separate argument.

Comment: Alex is right, remove the htmlAttributes from CheckBoxFor. Setting @value within them is messing up the bindings that CheckBoxFor already provides by you giving it the lambda 'model => model.IsActive'.

Comment: I understand that is the correct way to construct the CheckBoxFor, but even without HtmlAttributes I still get "False, false" back in the model when the checkbox is initialized as false then is checked. I know that I should be getting back "True, false", but I'm not.

Comment: Fyi, I recreated your problem exactly as you describe and then fixed it by removing the attributes. So I understand your frustration and it suggests there may be something else going on here. Do you have model.IsActive referenced anywhere else in your view?

Comment: No, model.IsActive is only referenced there. For a brief moment I thought maybe the view had been cached in the browser with the HtmlAttributes still being generated, but I cleared my browser cache and ran the project again without the HtmlAttributes, same behaviour.

Comment: Well I feel incredibly stupid, model.IsActive WAS referenced at the bottom of the page in this piece of code             <script>
    $("#IsActive").val("@Model.IsActive");
</script>     I had it there because the checkbox wasn't rendering the original value properly before (likely because of HtmlAttributes), but that JS was overwritting the value of the checkbox. It works fine now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change the `value` property of the checkbox. If yu use the helper without it you will see that

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive)
```

is rendered to

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsActive field is required." id="IsActive" name="IsActive" type="checkbox" value="true" class="valid">
```

You can see that although the `Model.IsActive` is set to false the value property of an input is still `true`

By The way if you look at the source code for CheckBox helper you will see that `value=true` is hardcoded there (So you should not change it):

```
private static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, string name, bool? isChecked, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
        {
            RouteValueDictionary attributes = ToRouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);

            bool explicitValue = isChecked.HasValue;
            if (explicitValue)
            {
                attributes.Remove("checked"); // Explicit value must override dictionary
            }

            return InputHelper(htmlHelper,
                               InputType.CheckBox,
                               metadata,
                               name,
                               value: "true",
                               useViewData: !explicitValue,
                               isChecked: isChecked ?? false,
                               setId: true,
                               isExplicitValue: false,
                               format: null,
                               htmlAttributes: attributes);
        }
```

Comment: You are correct, but the issue is that when the checkbox is created with an initial value of false (model.IsActive is passed in as false) and I check the checkbox to change the value to true it still gets passed back in the post as false. The value of the checkbox isn't changing.

Comment: You, as well as the commentors further up were correct, I explained the specific cause of my problem as a comment in the last post if you're curious. I've accepted your post as the correct answer.